# R dataframe subset: look for value in list

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe `df` made of strings (`character`) and lists of strings. Let's take following example :

```
Name       Nationality
'Alice'    "USA"
'Bob'      "MEX"
'Eve'      c("USA", "MEX")
```

That is:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Eve"), Nationality = list(    "USA", "MEX", c("USA", "MEX"))), .Names = c("Name", "Nationality"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

How to extract all rows that have *at least* "MEX" as nationality?

Expected output:

```
Name       Nationality
'Bob'      "MEX"
'Eve'      c("USA", "MEX")
```

---

**Edit:** I've tried:

- `df[df$Nationality == "MEX", ]` , but it only returns Bob.
- `df[df$Nationality %in% "MEX",]` but only Bob is returned . (idem for `...  %in% c("MEX"),]`)
- `df["MEX" %in% df$Nationality,]` returns all values, just like `df[is.element("MEX", df$Nationality),]`

Only `df[grep("MEX", df$Nationality), ]` is working...

Comment: Use `grep` if the third entry is "USA, MEX" i.e. `df[grep("MEX", df$Nationality), ]`.  Please use `dput` to show the example

Comment: If you check the code, it is doing the `subset`

Comment: @akrun yep, it does (and so your code is solving my issue). thank you! I'll edit my question to have a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Nationality' column is a `list` of length 3.  So, we can loop over the columns to check if there is `any` "MEX" `%in%` the `list` elements to get a logical `vector` and subset the rows based on that

```
df[sapply(lapply(df$Nationality, `%in%`, "MEX"), any),]
#    Name Nationality
#2  Bob         MEX
#3  Eve    USA, MEX
```

It can also be simplified as

```
df[sapply(df$Nationality, function(x) "MEX" %in% x),]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is far more logical (and explicit thanks to your explanation) than `grep`, even if result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
df["MEX" %in% df$Nationality,]
```

or

```
df[is.element("MEX", df$Nationality),]
```

Comment: Actually not working on my example. (but akrun's solution (`df[grep("MEX", df$Nationality), ]`) does). I making it reproducible with `dput`

Comment: That must mean the value under `df$Nationality` is not `c("USA", "MEX")` (in fact, you can't store vector-valued entries within a dataframe... I forgot about that). As @akrun said, most likely it is stored as a single string `"USA, MEX"` where `grep` would be the correct way to obtain your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse example:

```
example_tibble <-
  tibble::tibble(
    Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Eve"),
    Nationality = list("USA", "MEX", c("USA", "MEX"))    
  )

example_tibble_filtered <- example_tibble %>% 
  dplyr::filter(
    purrr::map_lgl(
      Nationality, ~ "MEX" %in% .)
  )
```